# Cognito User Pools with API Gateway

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I don't understand why my User Pool will not Authenticate a method in my API.

I've started with the simple petstore example, and added an Authorizer for my user pool. The test button shows that the JWT I have is working. I applied that Authorizer to the POST method on `/pets`, added Authorization as a request header.

When POST to `/pets` with postman (or curl), passing the `Authorization: Bearer <token>` header I always get the response `{"message":"Unauthorized"}`

I've messed around with creating an Identity pool linked to the User pool, with an Authenticated role that has a policy allowing access to the API Gateway. I've created a group in the User Pool to assign this group.

There's got to be some piece I'm missing. All I want to to allow access to the POST method to any user that presents a valid ID JWT from Cognito.

The policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "execute-api:Invoke"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:*:XXX/*/POST/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Which works fine in the simulator. I'm not 100% sure the policy should even be in play though. I'm not clear on how the provided User Pool authenticator would acquire the policy, it wasn't in any docs I saw. I just started throwing darts at the wall.

Would just like to hear that anyone has secured an API Gateway endpoint with a Userpool.

Comment: Can you post the policy that is allowing access to API Gateway? Note, that the action needs to be "execute-api:Invoke" not "apigateway:*" (which is for API management APIs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me works without "Bearer" in the Authorization's header using Postman.

Comment: Can't up vote this enough. It's the same from curl though, so it's not Postman's fault "^Bearer\s" is documented as being required. But my experience is showing that the Authorization: header should be only the Id JWT

Comment: Is setting the policy necessary? I've set the authorizor on my API function to use the correct cognito user pool and passing in the id_token returned from the built-in login page, but I'm getting "Unauthorized" message. (I tried setting policy as your example but getting "Please check the policy syntax and ensure that Principals are valid")